# DAO.Recordset AddNew

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I wanted to know if you can and how do you keep adding records or loop records to a table until I reach a certain date 1/1/2121 for a field? I changed my code to a sub and I could call it like FilltbluBoughtVacation 2013, 2021

BUT I thought that would work and im getting an error '3134' Syntax error in insert into statement and debug takes me to CurrentDb.Execute strSql.

```
Public Sub FilltbluBoughtVacation(StartYear As Integer, EndYear As Integer)

Dim BoughtYear As Date
Dim CurrentYear As Integer

For CurrentYear = StartYear To EndYear
    BoughtYear = CDate("01/01/" & CurrentYear)
    InsertBoughtVacation BoughtYear

Next CurrentYear
End Sub

Public Sub InsertBoughtVacation(BoughtVacDate As Date)
Dim strSql As String
strSql = "Insert into [tbluBoughtVacation] ([BoughtVacDate]) values (#" & Format([BoughtVacDate], "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# ,)"
Debug.Print strSql
CurrentDb.Execute strSql

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question, the goal and process not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is too little for two functions, and calling SQL in a loop is way too slow. Thus:

```
Public Sub FilltbluBoughtVacation(StartYear As Integer, EndYear As Integer)

    Dim rs AS DAO.Recordset

    Dim Sql As String
    Dim CurrentYear As Integer

    Sql = "Select Top 1 EmployeeID, BoughtYear From tbluBoughtVacation"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql)

    For CurrentYear = StartYear To EndYear
        rs.AddNew
            rs("EmployeeID").Value = Me!txtEmployeeID.Value 
            rs("BoughtYear").Value = DateSerial(CurrentYear, 1, 1)
        rs.Update
    Next
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response... I get a error '3061' To few parameters. Expected 1. and debug takes me to...  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql)

Comment: That typically indicates a missing or misspelled field name (or table name).

Comment: One last question before I do. I had a field EmployeeID that needed updated in the tbluBoughtVacation as well.  But im running this from a button and I want to pull the data from a text box for the EmployeeID field. Something like... Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbluBoughtVacation", dbOpenDynaset)
        rs.AddNew
        rs!EmployeeID = Me.txtEmployeeID